# Wanted to know about getChildHtml

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, products-management, layout, widget

Wanted to know , what does getChildHtml() does .need to know the flow of control?

Answer (score 5):

`getChildHtml()` is used to call the child block inside a file corresponding to parent block.

i.e. if you are in a phtml file (say app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml), it will be first declared in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml like following:

```
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
...
    <block type="yourmodule/block_name" name="any_name" template="your_folder/xyz.phtml">
...
</block>
```

**note:**

- `<block type="yourmodule/block_name" name="any_name" template="your_folder/xyz.phtml">` is a custom block which is the child of **category.products** block.
- where your_module is the module name (in lowercase) and block_name represent `app/code/local/Your_Namespace/YourModule/Block/Name.php`

> now, in catalog/category/view.phtml if you call $this->getChildHtml('any_name');, **xyz.phtml** contents will be rendered there.
>
> getChildHtml() [without parameters] render all the children.

for more details go through these links.

1. [Layouts for a module](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part2-series-layouts)
2. [Blocks and Layouts](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part5-series-model-blocks-layours)
3. [Advanced Layouts](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part3-series-advanced-layouts)

Comment: Addition: getChildHtml() only works if the block itself has a name in the layout, otherwise the result is always empty. See: http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-layout-getchildhtml-mit-leerem-ergebnis/

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to include the contents of a secondary Block/Template inside of a primary Block/Template.

Blocks calling Blocks calling Blocks is how the entire HTML layout for your page is created.

`getChildHtml()` returns the html of the block or all the blocks if you don't pass any parameters.